# Gulp Static i18n: href interpolation does not work

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, internationalization

I am using gulp with the plugin `gulp-static-i18n-html`, but I am facing an issue with interpolating links. Regular data attributes work without issues.

Current input

```html
<a data-attr-t data-attr-t-interpolate href-t="{{link-prefix}}page.html" data-t="header.title">
</a>
```

`en.json`

```json
{
    "link-prefix": "/fr/",
    "header": {
         "title": "Home"
    }
}
```

Current output

```html
<a href="page.html">Home</a>
```

Expected output

```html
<a href="/fr/page.html">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### TLDR

This problem could be due to you using `panini` or other plugins that use the same syntax as `gulp-static-i18n-html` for interpolation (`{{}}`), make sure the syntax is different for each library and it should work well.

#### Detailed breakthrough of the problem

In my gulp build process, I have used a plugin called `panini`. This plugin
compiles a series of HTML pages using a common layout and it uses a special syntax.

Example:

```
<!-- Header up here -->
{{> body}}
<!-- Footer down here -->
```

If you noticed, the prefix and the suffix of this syntax are exactly the same as the one `gulp-static-i18n-html` uses for interpolation. And since this plugin runs first, it was the reason why interpolation didn't work.
The solution at this point was simple, override the default suffix and prefix for one of these plugins and make them different.

Since panini was set up for the whole project, overriding the default prefix would've been a pain so I decided to override the other plugin.

One thing to keep in mind `gulp-static-i18n-html` is built on top of `static-i18n` which uses `i18next` to translate. I noticed in the documentation that the library has an option to pass configuration to `i18next`, this meant I could override the default suffix and prefix if I passed this

```js
staticI18nHtml({
  ...
  i18n: {
    interpolation: { 
      prefix: "%{",
      suffix: "}",
    }      
  } 
})
```

After trying this, I realized another problem. This did not work, and the interpolation template remained the same.

Once I realized this, I decided to dive deep into the source code for both the library and its dependencies.

`gulp-static-i18n-html` passed all its options to `static-i18n`, which passed them to `i18next` which was fine. But then I realized the actual interpolation of the attributes is done by `static-i18n` and they did not use the options but instead hardcoded the prefix and suffix in the regex string used to replace attribute strings.

After realizing this, I fixed the library in a local fork and I will be using that instead.